# Adding custom objects to binary search tree

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree

I am still fairly new to generics and binary search trees, and I am trying to add a custom `Student` object to a BST, and don't know exactly how to go about implementing it. I have my `Student` class declaration like follows:

```
class Student <E>implements Serializable, Comparable {

int studentNumber;

String firstName;
String lastName;
String major;
double gpa;

Student leftChild;
Student rightChild;

public Student() {
    this(0, "", "", "", 0.0);
} // end no-argument studentNumberRecordSerializable constructor

public Student(int sNum, String first, String last, String major, double gpa) {
    setstudentNumber(sNum);
    setFirstName(first);
    setLastName(last);
    setMajor(major);
    setGPA(gpa);
} // end four-argument studentNumberRecordSerializable constructor
....
```

and then my Node class:

```
class TreeNode<E extends Comparable<E>> {

TreeNode<E> leftNode;
E data;
TreeNode<E> rightNode;

public TreeNode(E nodeData) {
    data = nodeData;
    leftNode = rightNode = null; 
} // end TreeNode constructor

public void insert(E insertValue) {

    if (insertValue.compareTo(data) < 0) {

        if (leftNode == null)
            leftNode = new TreeNode<E>(insertValue);
        else
            leftNode.insert(insertValue);
    } // end if
....
```

and then I'm trying to to declare `Tree<Student> tree = new Tree<Student>();` and it is saying that that student is an invalid argument. I want also call `tree.insertNode(new Student(studentNumber, firstName, lastName, major, gpa));`to add it to the node. Is there an extra step that I am not following or something I am not doing right? I have done a lot of research on generics and also BSTs but I am having troubles tying the two together. please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix **Student** class declaration:

```
class Student implements Serializable, Comparable<Student> {
```

Comment: do I need to implement Comparable<Student> in the class I'm creating the tree in too?